# Intermittent firestore timeouts locking the whole client

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

First time poster here, despite 30+ years of programming experience. Something about firestore python client lib is driving me mad.

App is serving traffic and using firestore for persistence. Gunicorn running @ cloud run. Firestore document .get and .set operations sometimes time out. The timeout is not controllable by the publicly exposed APIs of the client library.

All firestore blocking operations I am wrapping in sync_to_async().

All .get() operations are also wrapped with asyncio.wait_for(...) with a timeout, and that works.

For .set() operations it seems impossible to enforce any kind of timeout, since public api does not have any methods for it, and wait_for(...) does not interrupt the wrapped blocking code. So when those fail, the client http requests are terminated by the ESP running in front of the backend service. Not ideal, since I could handle it better within the backend (e.g. retry, or fallback safely).

I'd very much appreciate help in figuring out how to enforce a timeout on firestore document set() operations. The app is user facing and accepting the default timeout which I think is 2 minutes or so, is just not practical. I'd rather report a failure, or retry.

Furthermore, I observed that every few days when a firestore operation fails with such a timeout, and the affected request is timed out by the nginx ESP running in front of it, the state of the firestore client is somehow corrupted, preventing any subsequent writes from being possible. What helps is re-creating the firestore client object.

I am on the verge of switching to a different database project because of inability to control timeouts, or getting native async support.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Sample code:

```
try:
    document = await asyncio.wait_for(db_get_fs(collection_name, id, trace), timeout=DB_GET_HARD_TIMEOUT_S)
    return document
```

...

```
async def db_get_fs(collection_name, id, trace):
    try:
        logger.info(f"DB_GET_{trace}: {collection_name}. {id}")
        document = await sync_to_async(fs_collections[collection_name].document(id).get)()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per now there is no way to adjust the Cloud Firestore timeout values. However there are some feature requests [[1]](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/131) [[2]](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/25) in the Python client library for Firestore asking for this improvement.

On the other hand, the fact you are only getting errors for the `.set()` operation might be due you are trying [to edit a document more than once in a second](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document):

> You should not update a single document more than once per second. If
> you update a document too quickly, then your application will
> experience contention, including higher latency, timeouts, and other
> errors.

Comment: tx. i get errors for both gets and sets; it's just for gets i can impose my own timeout by async wrapper, for set it never yields so it's not possible to cancel a long runing op. today my service was down for 7 seconds due to persistent timeouts, and i am thinking about jumping ship to a different db. btw, whoever thought about setting uncontrollable timeouts? how is that a good idea? beats me.

Comment: I believe this is by design as the library uses GRPC on the underlying interface, but maybe you can open a discussion in the in the [GitHub of the Python Cloud Firestore client library](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues).